# Parse.com query database for business intelligence and statistics purposes

Tags: json, csv, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

i would love to know how do i periodically run some complex queries on my app's Parse database? We are currently exporting the entire database as JSON, converting the JSON to CSV and putting it in an Excel and getting business intelligence data on that. It is not very efficient because the database is growing everyday and the process of converting the file to CSV is taking longer everyday. Any advice or good practices that you guys used?

Answer (score 0):

Parse's own "Background Jobs": http://blog.parse.com/announcements/introducing-background-jobs/

A meaningful answer would probably require more specifics but it is normal that bigger data = longer processing times.
One way of keeping a lid would be to keep processed data, processed :P and just appending your new results to that (differencials).

Comment: However, trying to get data on the go would be very difficult because i could not write queries and get the result the same way direct querying to a SQL database provides.

Comment: From what I interpret, either the data is processed in Excel (or whatever csv viewer you are using) or in the conversion JSON->CSV. If you process (not list) the data periodically and append to what was already processed (you can stay in parse or insert in another solution) the processing time will stabilize instead of continuously growing